# gitweb and gitolite cannot add new repo

Tags: git, gitolite

I installed gitolite first, and added some user and some repos, everything was fine. I then added gitweb, and could see repos through apache instance (just gitweb, no gitdaemon). The problem now comes in that I cannot add new repositories any more. Every time I pushed a change of gitolite-admin conf file, there were always 2 lines shown up in the log

```
remote: FATAL: git config 'gitweb.description' not allowed
remote: check GIT_CONFIG_KEYS in the rc file
```

Despite these 2 annoying lines, the conf file is indeed changed every time. I tried to stop apache instance, but still no luck :-(

I googled and cannot find any similar match to discuss this issue. Anyone can help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: And what is the value of `GIT_CONFIG_KEYS` in your `~/.gitolite.rc` file?

Comment: @VonC it is an empty string ' '

Comment: Can you set it to '`.*`' (see my answer below) and try pushing again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Gitolite g2-g3 migration page](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2migr-example.html) mentions:

> Now go to your old clone, and push it:

```
$ cd old.ga
$ gitolite push -f
    ...usual git progress output deleted...
remote: FATAL: git config foo.bar not allowed
remote: check GIT_CONFIG_KEYS in the rc file
To /home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git
 + 7eb8163...1474770 master -> master (forced update)
```

> Aaha! I forgot to set `GIT_CONFIG_KEYS` (new name for `GL_GITCONFIG_KEYS`) in the new rc file so fix that:

```
$ vim ~/.gitolite.rc
(edit and set it to `.*` for now)
```

Make sure your `.gitolite.rc` does contain:

```
GIT_CONFIG_KEYS             =>  '.*',
```

(It was also mentioned in this [GitLab issue](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1904), even though it wasn't the direct root cause of the issue)

---

> I got another issue which is my `projects.list` file does not get updated automatically when I added a new repository to `gitolite-admin` conf.
>   For gitweb, I had to manually edited that file. Did you know what could possibly cause that?

The "[interfacing with external tools](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/external.html)" page mentions:

> The list of gitweb-readable repos is written to a file whose name is given by the `rc` file variable `GITWEB_PROJECTS_LIST`.
>   The default value of this variable, if it is not specified or empty, is `$HOME/projects.list`.

Make sure you have in your `.gitolite.rc`:

```
GITWEB_PROJECTS_LIST        => '/path/to/projects.list',
```

Comment: that is exactly the solution!! Thx! I got another issue which is my projects.list file does not get updated automatically when I added a new repository to gitolite-admin conf. For gitweb, I had to manually edited that file. Did you know what could possibly cause that? Thanks again!!

Comment: @Sheng Make sure to have a line in your `.gitolite.rc` like `GITWEB_PROJECTS_LIST        => '/path/to/projects.list',`

Comment: For 2nd question, I tried your suggestion, but it did not work. I think you might misinterpret my 2nd question... This has nothing to do with gitweb. What I am asking is when I added a new repo through editing gitolite-admin conf, the new repo was not automatically added to the file "projects.list" Sorry to bring up so many questions -- I picked up this work from my colleague who has some emergence to take care of.

Comment: @Sheng I understand (nothing to do with gitweb), but still, try to add this line just in case it has an effect on the `projects.list` file  when you are pushing new commits to `gitolite-admin`

Comment: @Sheng is it a right issue, ie if you `chmod 777` that file, would it work better? Do you see anything in the gitolite log?